# Json.NET Serialize Object Properties Without Parent

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Using Json.NET is it possible to serialize an object's fields instead of the object itself?

In JMS Serializer (PHP) I can use the [@Inline](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#inline) annotation.

```
public class ApiResponseData
{
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

If I serialize ApiResponseData I would like to get just username, firstname and lastname, not the User property.

**Actual:** `{ "user": { "username": "username", "firstname": "firstname", "lastname": "lastname" } }`
**Desired:** `{ "username": "username", "firstname": "firstname", "lastname": "lastname" }`

Comment: what the problem with using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject( apiResponseData.User)` ?

Comment: @Alex I left out a bit of context but ApiResponseData implements ApiResponse and should have a User as its body (but without the "user" property serialized" since I am using User as an entity class). Other ApiResponse classes may have other classes/properties.

Comment: You can override with a custom json converter. like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40862660/how-to-inline-a-property-in-resulting-json-with-json-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to serialize `ApiResponseData.User` instead of serializing `ApiResponseData` itself. This way it will only serialize the values of 
`ApiResponseData.User`. Like:

```
 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ApiResponseData.User);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing right now. It is not a very clean solution, the @Inline annotation of JMS is quite useful. Can you confirm that there is no such attribute in Json.NET?

Answer (score 0):

In the classes that contain objects of this class, you can add internal properties that return the value of the member you wish to serialize. Not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Comment: This is useful for scenarios where we can't use reflection in a custom converter. For example, with netstandard 1.1.